# how to set equal two character values I tried but I cannot do it it compiled but don't support to if function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    
     char marital[5];
     printf("enter your marital details-");
     scanf("%s",&marital);

     if(marital=="male"){        
        printf("you are insured");
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `strcmp` instead of checking with `==`.

Comment: Any basic C course teaches you this. Don't try to learn C the hard way.

Comment: can please type correct statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char gender[7];

scanf("%s",&gender);
char *message=(!strcmp(gender,"male"))?"gender is male":"gender is female";
printf("%s\n",message);
```

Comment: Female requires 7 characters not 5

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strcmp()`to compare char arrays (strings) in C Programming Language.
Also remember to add the string ending char '\0'.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INSURED "You are insured\n"
int main () {
        char marital[5];

        int n = read(0, marital, 5);
        marital[n - 1] = '\0';

        if ( strcmp(marital, "male") == 0 ) {
                write(1, INSURED, strlen(INSURED));
        }

        return 0;
 }
```

`strcmp()` returns an integer

- **0**    if strings are equal
- **> 0** if the first non-matching character in str1 is greater (in ASCII) than that of str2.
- **< 0**    if the first non-matching character in str1 is lower (in ASCII) than that of str2.

Comment: As the compiler already adds the `\0` to any string literal, how would it be possible to forget it?

Comment: @ImtiasBakar Use my updated code, it uses File Descriptors and Systems Calls and works fine. I've already tested it.
I don't know why my answer got downvoted...

Comment: Why are you using `read` when it doesn't really add anything useful to the question though? It's not portable and there are better ways of taking strings as input specifically. `write` also seems really unnecesary...

Comment: It is portable across POSIX systems

Comment: @JiahuiChen sorry for downvoted it was a mistake done by me thankyou for  explaining problem and everything

Comment: @stark does scanf puts \0 at the end? Please clarify

Comment: @stark scanf doesn't put a '\0' at the end. That function reads input from the standard input stream `stdin`. Actually, what you get is the input + '\n' because of the Enter key. That's why I'm changing the last '\n' for '\0'

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- `main()` should not return `void`. Its proper return value in an `int`.
- You don't need to pass the address of `marital` to `scanf()` since strings in C are just pointers to arrays of `char`.
- `scanf()` is a dangerous function. You should not use it to read user input. Use `fgets()` function, it reads an entire line and is much safer.
- `if(marital=="male")` you are basically comparing two pointers, not the actual strings. You have to use `strcmp()`.

That said, here's how your code should be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strcmp()

int main()
{
    char marital[5];
    printf("Enter your marital details: ");
    fgets(marital, sizeof marital, stdin);
    marital[strcspn(marital, "\n")] = `\0`; // fgets reads \n too so remove it

    if(strcmp(marital, "male") == 0)
        printf("you are insured");
}
```